# Wordpress auto activate custom theme after installation

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Always use a custom wordpress theme.
Is it possible that after installing Wordpress my custom theme is automatically activated?

Comment: please consider asking at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more for wordpress exchange network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description

> Switches current theme to new template and stylesheet names.  Accepts
>   one argument: $stylesheet of the theme. ($stylesheet is the name of
>   your folder slug. It's the same value that you'd use for a child
>   theme, something like `twentythirteen`.) It also accepts an additional
>   function signature of two arguments: $template then $stylesheet. This
>   is for backwards compatibility.

Usage

```
<?php switch_theme( $stylesheet ) ?>
```

Optional usage for backwards compatibility:

```
<?php switch_theme( $template, $stylesheet ) ?>
```

here is reference [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme)